# Firebase Two-Factor Auth in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a flutter app and I am using firebase for authentication purpose. I have a website as well, I recently implemented 2 Factor Auth using firebase.

On the web side, I login the user, catch the Mfa error and using the resolver proceed with the OTP verification via the phone number or email.

I am trying to implement the same thing on the flutter side, While I have found the modules for implementing recaptcha and OTP verification, I am unable to figure out the resolver bit, Any help would be appreciated. I read on some posts that MFA is not possible with Flutter as of this moment, is this so ? I have been unable to find anything on the docs so far regarding mfa for flutter.

Here is what I have so far :

```
void attemptLogin() async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      //  Add logic for non 2fa users
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
      if (err.code == 'second-factor-required') {
        // Use the resolver and intiate recaptcha and OTP verification process. How to do this ?
      } else {
        // Show relevant erro message
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

firebase_auth multi-factor authentication is still in progress as mentioned on this [thread](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/7290). MFA has been available on [web](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa) and native mobile SDKs for a while now. Flutter has added MFA feature on their [roadmap](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/7290#issuecomment-972807314), but no ETA at present.

Comment: Closing since MFA is now available